# Adding tasks to existing group or chord

Tags: celery, celery-task

consider following scenario;

There are 3 different type of tasks. `A`, `B` and `C`. `A` is meant to produce an input for `B` and `B` is supposed to create many `C` tasks after receiving an input from `A`.

At the start, i can only be able to define `group(A, B)` as `C`s are executed by `B`. But i want to wait for all `C` tasks to be finished as well in order to conclude that main task is done.

Is there a way of doing that by using celery utilities?

Answer (score 0):

The solution i use so far is waiting for `C` tasks inside `B`.

Something like;

```
from celery.result import allow_join_result

def B():
    tasks = get_c_tasks()

    g = group(tasks)
    gr = g.apply_async()
    with allow_join_result():
        return gr.join(propagate=False)
```